# SharePoint 2010 Ribbon Customization Without Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, ribbon

I am exploring different options for a tool I am looking to migrate to SharePoint 2010.

The current tool is in Excel and uses the ribbon customization options extensively. This would go nicely with SharePoint 2010 and the ribbon that is now available.

The problem is that I don't have access to the back-end servers for our company's SharePoint 2010 environment (therefore no Visual Studio publishing, etc.) so would like to explore options of "injecting" the custom ribbon XML via JavaScript (or something else) when the specific page loads.

High level flow would be the following.

1. User loads page
2. JavaScript code is executed on page load (jQuery, prototype, whatever) which dynamically builds the custom ribbon components.
3. User can now interact with the new ribbon components like normal.

From what I have read the ribbon is just HTML and JS so something like this *should* be feasible I would think. Would like to know if anyone has done anything similar in the past.